# How can I create a PDA account dynamically or conditionally

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang

[Anchor docs](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/PDAs.html#how-to-build-pda-hashmaps-in-anchor) show how to create PDA accounts via the account validation struct:

```
// validation struct
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateUserStats<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    // space: 8 discriminator + 2 level + 4 name length + 200 name + 1 bump
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = user,
        space = 8 + 2 + 4 + 200 + 1, seeds = [b"user-stats", user.key().as_ref()], bump
    )]
    pub user_stats: Account<'info, UserStats>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
```

But how can we create accounts dynamically, only when they don't exist for instance. I have seen an example using `accounts.system_program.create_account()`:

```
/// pseudo code
fn initialize(accounts) {
    accounts.system_program.create_account(accounts.payer, accounts.counter);
    let counter = deserialize(accounts.counter);
    counter.count = 0;
}
```

but I don't know if there is something like this for creating PDA accounts (including seeds and bump).

So in summary:

1. **How can we check if a PDA account already exist within a function (not using struct).**
2. **How can we create a PDA account within a function (not using struct).**
3. **Is there a way to create a PDA account using struct only if doesn't exist already?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The best way to see what Anchor is currently doing is to use [`anchor expand`](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cli#expand) to see the expanded macros. Then you can pull that logic inside your own function.*

> 1. How can we check if a PDA account already exist within a function (not using struct).

I believe Anchor just checks the account balance, e.g. `my_account.lamports()`.

Please note even if the account does exist, Anchor does a few extra things:

- Ensures the account size matches the requested space, even allocating extra space via CPI if required
- Ensures there is enough balance for the requested account size, even transferring lamports from payer via CPI, if it is short
- Ensures the right program is assigned to the account, even assigning owner via CPI if required

> 2. How can we create a PDA account within a function (not using struct).

This is how Anchor does it under the hood:

```
let (__pda_address, __bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
    &[<seeds>],
    program_id,
);

let cpi_accounts = anchor_lang::system_program::CreateAccount {
    from: payer.to_account_info(),
    to: my_account.to_account_info(),
};
let cpi_context = anchor_lang::context::CpiContext::new(
    system_program.to_account_info(),
    cpi_accounts,
);
anchor_lang::system_program::create_account(
    cpi_context
        .with_signer(
            &[
                &[
                    <seeds>,
                    &[__bump][..],
                ][..],
            ],
        ),
    lamports,
    space as u64,
    program_id,
)?;
```

> 3. Is there a way to create a PDA account using struct only if doesn't exist already?

You can use [`init_if_needed`](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.Accounts.html#constraints) in your Accounts struct to instruct Anchor to create an account if only it does not already exist.

This feature is susceptible to re-initialisation attacks so it is not enabled by default. You can enable it in your `Cargo.toml` by adding `init-if-needed` feature to `anchor-lang`.

Comment: Re: your answer to the third question, there is `init_if_needed`. https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.Accounts.html#constraints

Comment: Hmm not sure what I was smoking to have forgotten about that. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `Anchor expand` @sohrab ?  Is that a package? an option or command within VSCode editor?

Comment: It's part of the CLI: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cli#expand I'll add the link to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to have a separate functions for

- initializing accounts / PDAs
- using those accounts / PDAs

Then typically you leave it up to your front end / client code to check whether or not it needs to include an initialization function, based on whether an account already exists or not.